# AngularJS Reformat Time String

Tags: angularjs, datetime

I have an AngularJS App which requests data from another system. One part of the Data is a time (independent from the day) in 24hr format with Seconds and milliseconds like this:

```
11:15:00.000
```

Whats the best way to format it with Javascript / AngularJS to a format like this:

```
11:15
```

Greetings

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: Yes I know this page, but I do not have a date. I just have the time string

Comment: I suggest you to use [momentjs library](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the format is always the same, you can simply limit it to 5 characters using a built-in Angular filter and the resulting string will always be in `hh:mm` format, i.e.:

```
<span>{{'11:15:00.000' | limitTo:5}}</span>
```

Will output `11:15`.

You can use this filter inside the js code like that:

```
var d = $filter('limitTo')('11:15:00.000', 5);
```

If the format might be different, then you should use something like moment.js